# Crontab Launches Python Script but SystemD Does Not?

Tags: python, django, unix, amazon-ec2, systemd

I can log into my AWS EC2 server via ssh and type:

```
cd /opt/myWebApp
sudo python3 /opt/myWebApp/manage.py myCronJob
```

...and it runs.

I can also launch the same script via crontab:

```
0 */6 * * * sudo python3 /opt/myWebApp/manage.py myCronJob --settings=server.settings.production
```

But when I try to run it in SystemD, with .service file:

```
ExecStart='/usr/bin/python3.7' /opt/myWebApp/manage.py myCronJob --settings=server.settings.production
```

...I get:

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

`$PYTHONPATH` and `$VIRTUAL_ENV` are empty. `/opt/myWebApp/server_venv` is empty as well. There's a python at `/usr/bin/python3.7`, but I'm referencing that in the SystemD .service file as noted above, and it's throwing that error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you confirm that `python3.7` and `python3` point to the same environment?

Comment: How can I check to find that out?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`, `which python3`

Comment: I ran `cd /usr/bin/` and `which python3` and it returned `/usr/bin/python3`.  But running `ls -l pyth*.*` shows there is no file named `python3` -- just `python3.6`, `python3.7`, etc. ???

Comment: @VikR `ls -l pyth*.*` would not find `python3` because it has no dot in its name. Try `ls -l /usr/bin/pyth*`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, good catch! Okay, now I see that `/usr/bin/python3` points to `/etc/alternatives/python3`. I changed my .service file to `ExecStart='/etc/alternatives/python3' /opt/myWebApp/manage.py myCronJob --settings=server.settings.production`.  But I'm still getting the `Couldn't import Django` error. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

```
ExecStart='/etc/alternatives/python3' ./manage.py myCronJob --settings=server.settings.production
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myWebapp
User=myUser
```

The user ('myUser' in the above code) has access to Django.